# SQLite FOREIGN KEY REFERENCE is causing syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, syntax-error

I have the below SQL statements which is a minimal example of my code. I am getting a syntax error and have managed to narrow it down the line which is commented out. The code works fine when the line is commented out but throws a syntax error otherwise. I have gone over it and tried changing the names used but still can't avoid the error and I have no idea what is causing it because the line seems effectively identical to the other `FOREIGN KEY` line. I am trying to run this in a fresh SQLite instance, so start the SQLite command line and enter the following commands:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Xlanguage 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    xname VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE LibraryType 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    xname VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE Library 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    languageId INTEGER,
    -- FOREIGN KEY languageId REFERENCES Xlanguage(id),
    libraryTypeId INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(libraryTypeId) REFERENCES LibraryType(id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--FOREIGN KEY column
FOREIGN KEY(column)
```

I put brackets and it worked. I think you get error because of you already inserted tables. If these tables exist, drop them and try again.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed that. I was still getting an error and it turns out that I also need to put both of the foreign keys at the bottom like: CREATE TABLE Library (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  languageId INTEGER,
  libraryTypeId INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(languageId) REFERENCES Xlanguage(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(libraryTypeId) REFERENCES LibraryType(id)
);

Comment: @Max888 you could also use the column based (shorter) `CREATE TABLE Library (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  languageId INTEGER,
  libraryTypeId INTEGER REFERENCES LibraryType(id)
);`. However, you can't use column based for composite Foreign Keys.